# Are these queries the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, where-clause

is `SELECT a,b FROM foo` the same as `SELECT a,b FROM foo WHERE a=a and b=b`?

I am getting different results when I run them.

Ultimately, I am trying to set parameters for my SSRS report as :

`SET @a Varchar (20) 
DECLEARE @a = Null
SET @b Varchar (20) 
DECLEARE @b = Null
SELECT a,b 
FROM foo 
WHERE 
    a=isnull(@a,a) 
and b=isnull(@b,b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different results because there is a NULL somewhere in A or B. NULL does not equal NULL in SQL Server

Use this instead.

```
SELECT a, b FROM foo
WHERE (@a ISNULL or a =@a) AND (@b ISNULL or b=@b)
```

Also you need to DECLARE your variables before you SET them.

Comment: @H.Ben I added how to handle null parameters

Answer (score 0):

Both of the queries will not return same set of result based on having NULL value in a or b.

Simply because NULL is not equal to NULL.

Comment: This is not (always) true. OP stated he got different results.

Comment: Your answer is correct I didn't notice null is not equal to null.

Comment: It's a good thing to remember about SQL Server. This is important in COUNT(*) versus COUNT([column]) as well